# AsyncTask in fragments not updating UI

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, android-gridview

I am using `FragmentPagerAdapter` to swipe `Fragment` and using `AsyncTask` to update gridview but its not updating the UI.

Its not updating the UI and also not throwing any error I tried to check the flow and its running GalleryTab fragment twice...and unable to understand the problem .

My code:-

```
public class GalleryTab extends Fragment {
            GridView gridview;
            ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
            GridViewAdapter adapter;
            public List<GalleryList> phonearraylist = null;
            View view;
            private WeakReference<RemoteDataTask> asyncTaskWeakRef;

        public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
            GalleryTab f = new GalleryTab();
        return f;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery_tab, null);
             setRetainInstance(true);
                startNewAsyncTask();
            //new RemoteDataTask(this).execute();
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery_tab, container, false);
        }

        // RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
            private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
                private WeakReference<GalleryTab> fragmentWeakRef;

                private RemoteDataTask (GalleryTab gallerytab) {
                    this.fragmentWeakRef = new WeakReference<GalleryTab>(gallerytab);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();

                } 

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Create the array

                    phonearraylist = new ArrayList<GalleryList>();
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
                            GalleryList map = new GalleryList();
                            map.setGallery("http://oi39.tinypic.com/21oydxs.jpg");
                            System.out.println("PRINT!!!!--  "+ i);
                            phonearraylist.add(map);
                        }
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    // if (this.fragmentWeakRef.get() != null) {
                    adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), phonearraylist);
                    System.out.println("PRINT SIZE --  "+ phonearraylist.size());
                    gridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
                    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

                //  mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    // }
                }
            }
            private void startNewAsyncTask() {
                RemoteDataTask asyncTask = new RemoteDataTask(this);
                this.asyncTaskWeakRef = new WeakReference<RemoteDataTask >(asyncTask );
                asyncTask.execute();
            }
    }
```

Comment: you are calling asynctask twice? `startNewAsyncTask();
            new RemoteDataTask(this).execute()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find out your id of GridView onCreateView() method because it returns the view...

```
gridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
```

And yes if you have Make a object of View at intialize then just replace :

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery_tab, container, false);
```

to

```
return view;
```

Comment: And why are you execute RemoteDataTask twice?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the particular issue but it appears that there is a lot of weaving between the `RemoteDataTask` scope and the `GalleryTab`. Try setting your `RemoteDataTask` to static and everything you lose reference to you should be passing in to the `RemoteDataTask` constructor. Maybe this would help you get your debugging in line.

This:

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

To:

```
private static class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

This is the prefered way to deal with multiple threads (which is what AsyncTasks are).

Comment: its throwing :--Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getActivity() from the type Fragment

Comment: You would pass the context to `RemoteDataTask` and you would keep it as a weak reference or since you already have the fragment weakreference you can call: `fragmentWeakRef.get().getActivity();`